# What does (x & 0xff00) != 65280 do?

Tags: java, character

I'm working with legacy code and I see a lot of `(c & 0xff00) != 65280` for a character array (where c is a character). Can anyone tell me what this accomplishes?

Comment: Google `java operators`. Then google `java hexadecimal literal`.

Comment: bitwise operators in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: I understand bitwise operators and how it reaches the solution, but I'm wondering the reasoning behind using this. 65280, according to http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/, is 00000000, which means c had to be 0. Why not just directly check that then via "c == 0"?

Comment: 65280 is 0xff00.  Keep in mind that Java chars are two bytes wide, not one byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is testing if the high byte of the character is all ones, or more exactly, is not all ones.  The test succeeds - not all ones - if the character is neither in the unicode category "halfwidth and fullwidth forms" nor in the unicode category "specials", according to the following file:

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Blocks.txt